# why org.apache.commons.math3.* removed and what can be the alternatives

Tags: java, math, deprecated, apache-commons

I want to use GaussNewtonOptimizer in my project but I can't find package named math in `org.apache.commons`.

Is there any other package from apache or any third party package that I can use.

Comment: Do you have the `commons-math3` library?

Comment: I didn't know how to import these libraries or even if I could import them myself since I am new to Java and Ant. But now I know how to import it.

Comment: are you using maven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly get the [Apache-commons-math3](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/download_math.cgi) library and import this library in your project.

Answer (score 0):

This class was relocated: [org.apache.commons.math3.optimization.general.GaussNewtonOptimizer](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/optimization/general/GaussNewtonOptimizer.html)